# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in training word2vec

Tags: python, typeerror, text-mining, word2vec, word-embedding

I wrote this function and got the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. how can I fix it?

```
def get_words(txt):
   a=(lambda x: x not in STOP_WORDS), re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', txt)
   return a
```

```
def sentence_words(text):
    line = text.strip().lower()
    sent_tokenize1=sent_tokenize(line)
    sent_wordsmap=list(map(get_words,sent_tokenize1))
    return sent_wordsmap
```

```
sent_word=sentence_words(text)
model = Word2Vec(sent_word, size=128, window=3, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Are you trying to get output like `[['this', 'is', 'it'], ['that', 'is', 'it']]` from `sentence_words ` function?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `get_words` with this.

```
def get_words(txt):
   a = list(filter(lambda x: x not in STOP_WORDS, re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', txt)))
   return a
```